# Docker-compose Install: No module named docker.errors

Tags: docker, installation, docker-compose

I'm facing this issue when I'm installing docker-compose

OS: **ubuntu 14.04**

docker --version
Docker **version 17.05.0-ce**, build 89658be

pip freeze | grep docker
**docker==2.5.1**
**docker-pycreds**==0.2.1
**dockerpty==0.4.1**

pip install docker-compose
Installing collected packages: docker-compose
Successfully installed docker-compose-1.17.0

**docker-compose --version**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in 
from compose.cli.main import main
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 17, 
in from . import errors
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/errors.py", line 
11, in from docker.errors import APIError
ImportError: No module named docker.errors
```

Any solution for this error , thank you for your help.

Comment: Same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

I'm in later versions of those packages. But I had the exact same error and installing "requests" package in a recent version did fix the problem.

```
docker==3.5.0
docker-compose==1.22.0
docker-dev==1.0b2
docker-py==1.10.6
docker-pycreds==0.3.0
dockerpty==0.4.1
requests==2.18.4
```

However, I then got another error: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4401

Applying the change proposed in comments did the trick:

```
pip uninstall docker
pip uninstall docker-py
pip uninstall docker-compose
pip install docker-compose==1.9.0
```

Then I got into a third error: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/1916

That I fixed by uninstalling the docker-py pip package which is incompatible with the docker one.

Now docker-compose works.

Hope this helps.